# Nx and Angular: version of installed local library differs from browser one

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, angular-library, nrwl-nx

### Background:

I created two repositories: repository A (contains an Angular app) and repository B (contains an Angular library). Both repositories are cloned and developed on the local machine. The library from repository B is installed in repository A via `npm link`. The app from repository A uses the library from repository B (e.g. an Angular service).

Both repositories are created with Nx version 13.3.9. For a better understanding I simplified the complexity of this description. In reality both projects are big mono-repositories with more apps and libraries.

### Problem

I serve the App of repository A and open it with Chrome. Whenever I've done changes to the library of repository B I build that library and the ng-development-server from repository A recognizes the change and recompiles the app. I've checked if the changes made to the library in repository B are the same as the installed library in the `node_modules` folder of repository A. **That means the installed library in repository A and the build of repository B are correctly synchronized. But when I open the app with Chrome and I debug it with the webdev-tools I see the old version of the library without the new changes.**

### Suggestion

I think that this is some kind of caching problem, but I don't know how to fix it. I don't know why this happens and I don't know the origin of this problem.

### What I tried for now

- I've completely cleared the Chrome browser's cache and I restarted it many times
- I tried other web browsers like Firefox
- I tried to upgrade Nx to the latest version
- I removed the node_modules folder and installed all dependencies again
- I removed the cache from node_modules/.cache

### Attempt to reproduce this issue

I tried to reproduce this issue with two test repositories using Nx 13.3.9 without success. The new repositories somehow don't have this issue. I wanted to share an minimal example of this problem but I can't.

### Questions

How can I fix this problem and why does this happen? I know its harder to help without any code but the two "real" repositories are big ones and the installation is not easy. Unfortunately I can't share the code.

Comment: Does it work if you restart the ng-development-server manually after each change?

Comment: Do you mean calling `ng serve` again? No, it doesn't work.

Comment: My current assumption is that the problem has something to do with `preserveSymlinks`option. I'm doing more research

Comment: I personally never had a good experience with Symlinks and Angular. but how did you link them? did you run `npm link` manually or you used it in dependencies in package.json like this: `"dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar/dist/built-project"
  }` and running npm install should do all the job for you.

Comment: @EricAska I used `npm link`manually. As far as I know, installing packages via "file:../..." also creates symlinks the way `npm link`does. I tested it and it's the same problem.

Comment: I'm really interested to see if you managed to figure it out. :)

Comment: @EricAska yes, it was the preserveSymlinks option in angular.json (see my answer) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption in the comments section was correct: The problem was caused by the `preserveSymlinks` option in my `angular.json` file. I don't know why, but this option caused webpack to not update the symlinks properly after something had changed.

After changing the `preserveSymlinks` option from true to false I got an error:

```
inject() must be called from an injection context
```

One solution to solve this error would be to add the `preserveSymlinks`option again. But I didn't want to add it again and applied another solution: I added the following code to the `paths` attribute in `tsconfig.base.json`:

```
"paths": {
     "@angular/*": [
         "./node_modules/@angular/*"
     ],
...
```